# Configuring to run nunit test project in teamcity

Tags: nunit, teamcity

I have a vb.net project that runs nunit tests. I am struggling to even build this project right as it keeps giving the following error 'Type ' ' not defined. Any idea how to configure the teamcity to build and run scripts from project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some code isn't checked in properly, and TeamCity can't build because of that. Try to do a fresh checkout from your repository to a new folder, and build the project/solution there.

When the project builds, then we can look into getting it to test with NUnit.